# Symfony- passing an array of ids

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote an api with a function that sets notification as read by passing it's id.

But also, there should be an option to pass array of ids there, to mark several at once as read. I should extend function so that it handles the case where $this>data['id'] is an array.

Is this the right way?

My Service:

```
 public function read($id = []){

 $notification = $this->getRepository()->findBy([
        'id' => $id
    ]);

    if($notification) {
       $notification[0]->setRead(new \DateTime());
       $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function readAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams(['id']);
    $this->get('app')->read(
        $this->data['id']
    );

    return $this->success();
}
```

Comment: `findBy` searches by direct equal. So passing array of ids will not work.

Comment: Also instead of selecting and then persisting selected items, it is faster to create an update query: `UPDATE table SET read = true WHERE id IN (your ids)`

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is possible to pass an array of ids to `findBy()`; e.g: `findBy(['id' => [1, 2, 3]])`

Comment: @Yoshi snap! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed pass an array of `id` values to [`\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions); e.g:

```
$notifications = $this->getRepository()->findBy([
    'id' => [1, 2, 3] // etc.
]);
```

However, since `findBy()` can return multiple results, it will return an array (or array-like object like `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`). Therefore you should iterate over your result set:

```
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $notification->setRead(new \DateTime());
}

$this->em->flush();
```

Additionally, it's a matter of taste to some degree but you may want to make your API more explicit and create separate methods for a single action versus a group action; e.g:

```
public function read(int $id)
{
    //in this scenario you are searching for one notification
    // only so you can use `findOneBy()` instead
    $notification = $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    $notification->setRead(new \DateTime());
    $this->em->flush();
}

public function readMany(array $ids)
{
    $notification = $this->getRepository()->findBy(['id' => $ids]);

    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $notification->setRead(new \DateTime());
    }

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

As pointed out by @Yoshi, `read()` could also be neatly implemented as:

```
public function read(int $id)
{
    $this->readMany([$id]);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: A bit pedantic, but I'd refactor `read` to simply call `$this->readMany([$id]);`

Comment: Happy to help :) Good question!